# Why get Armor after Attack but before Shields?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

Whenever I watch a professional Protoss (usually WhiteRa) in replays of HotS, they usually get Armor (ground/air armor) after getting Attack but before getting Shields.

Why is that?

Comment: Your title and your text are asking two different things. Are you asking why armor before shield, or why attack before armor?

Comment: I edited the title to match the text, ken please clarify what you mean as you've said contradictory things. @Robotnik if he meant what was in the body then it's not a duplicate of that question

Comment: @Aequitas - The dupe target asks why shields are researched later than both Armour & Attack, this question asked why pros get armour before shield, but after attack. It's a similar question really with the same answer: Attack is important because damage dealt can be a defense in itself (kil something before it does more damage), Armour has more immediate benefit to your units, and Shields are expensive and don't provide that great of a buffer for your units. I've updated the title to reflect this however I don't think the question should be reopened.

Comment: @Robotnik I'm not sure if that's what they mean, it's a bit ambiguous as to what he means as the title was asking armor then shield, but the body was asking attack then armor. If it's the latter then the answer to this would be different; protoss usually go attack first against zerg because zealots will then two shot a zergling as opposed to three shots without the attack upgrade which makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Robotnik also the dupe question doesn't go into the order or attack and armor, only why shield is last, this is (maybe) asking about attack before armor or armor before attack. But i'm not sure it'd be good if they could clarify

Comment: @Aequitas It may be worth pointing out that Community closed this as a dupe, which means the asker confirmed it was a dupe.

Comment: @Frank oh okay, I guess that calrifies it,  nevermind then